# Conditional Formatting not updating when referencing new data from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a sheet called 'Email' in which I reference cells from the sheet 'CL Upcoming'. What I am finding is that when I add new rows to the 'CL Upcoming' sheet that the new rows in the 'Email' sheet are not showing. See row 43.

[image]

I can confirm that the data is pulling over, however. The highlighted cell on the right below was copied from the left highlighted cell.

[image]

Therefore, I can conclude the issue has to be related to my conditional formatting, where I essentially blank out a cell if the value is blank.

[image]

What I can't figure out is if my conditional formatting formulas are off or if I am doing something else wrong. Does anyone have any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every text that is inside another file is only loaded and cached upon opening the document or a manual refresh (F9). This is to ensure that there is no overhead and extreme slow down every time you make a change.

Once the cache of the file has updated all values of the remote worksheet, the conditional formatting will work right again.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another way to refresh the document? I tried F9 but it does not refresh it.

Comment: I found something online saying to do ctrl+alt+shift+F9. Doing the refresh did not help unfortunately.

Comment: It has been a long time ago. I vaguely remember that when you open a document it specifically asks you if you want to update the values. Might be the only time when it updates, unless you have both the source and the main document open at the same time, in which case it does update upon a refresh.